# Elasticsearch edge_ngram tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, tokenize, analyzer

I want to create edge_ngram tokenizer in elastic but with filter. For example, I have stored "30 G" text. With basic edge ngram tokenizer(from 1 to 10 size) it will split that text into [3, 30, 30(with space), 30 G]. 
Is it possible to somehow split my text by space and create only [30, 30 G] ngram? What I need to do additional to achieve that effect?

I want to do that, because if I have '30 G' string, I don't want to have results when I enter only '3'. 
It should work only when I search by type '30' or '30 G'

Comment: Effectively you want to split tokens by space and also keep the original one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch custom analyser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315141/elasticsearch-custom-analyser)